# IF EXISTS when creating table query

Tags: c#, sqlite

I need to write q query where I check if the table exists, and if it does I need to insert value in there. I'm always getting compile errors cause my syntax is wrong. Cab anyone please point out to me the proper code?Appreciate it

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createDataBase();
        createDataTable();
    }

    private void createDataBase()
    {
       SQLiteDataAdapter  dataBase = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
    }


    private SQLiteConnection getConnection() 
    { 
        return new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=file1.db"); 
    }


    private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
    {            
     using (SQLiteConnection sqlcon =  getConnection())
     {
            using (SQLiteCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlcmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
                sqlcon.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }


    private void createDataTable()
    {
        //ExecuteQuery("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'RECORDS'");
        //ExecuteQuery("CREATE TABLE RECORDS ( ID varchar(255))");
        //ExecuteQuery("CREATE TABLE (IF NOT EXISTS) 'RECORDS'");
        //("IF (EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM sqlite_master WHERE NAME = 'RECORDS'))");
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          AddValue(textBox1.Text);  
        ////ExecuteQuery("IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> NULL AND TABLE_NAME = 'RECORDS')) BEGIN INSERT INTO RECORDS (ID) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "')");    
    }


    private void AddValue(string value)
    {
      ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO RECORDS (ID) VALUES ('" + value + "')");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: post the compile errors.

Comment: SQLite error
near "RECORDS": syntax error

Comment: i tried all sorts of versions, can't copy them all here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example

```
  SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='MAIN'";
  SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if (rdr.HasRows)
  {
        cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE 'MAIN'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

but this is directly from the [SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html)

```
  SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST 'MAIN'";
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: hi Steve, I inserted exec query  because I couldnt understand how to implement your version of it. I now get an error telling that SQLite error no such table: RECORDS, however it would let me compile and run the code, until i insert something in textbox, can you please once again look at my code, i construct a proper version of it?thank you

Comment: It's difficult to say where is your problem from the code above. From the error message I suppose that you call the method datatable() and the table "RECORDS" doesn't exist in you SQLite database. However I can't see where your code call the method datatable(). The method ExecuteQuery() is correct, apart from two closing braces missing.

Comment: Hi Steve, well that's exactly where I'm having problems. I just can't figure out what is the correct way to construct it. If I choose to run this  ExecuteQuery("CREATE TABLE RECORDS ( ID varchar(255))"); >>>>>> it will run only once, and then give me error: RECORDS already exist. If I choose to run this   ExecuteQuery("CREATE TABLE (IF NOT EXISTS) 'RECORDS'"); it will give a syntax error, same thing happens with ExecuteQuery("IF (EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM sqlite_master WHERE NAME = 'RECORDS'))");.So, I am completely confused what is the correct way implementing the syntax for this query

Comment: Which kind of provider are you using for SQLite? I suppose the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --your insert logic
END
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested on SQLite. I hope it will because the given sample is in ANSI.

Comment: I tries to follow this pattern, but I always get compile errors.

Comment: Not sure why it is failing in your case. Following example is fully functional
in my case where I have a table called Person. Please post your actual SQL for more support.
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> NULL 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Person'))
BEGIN
    select * from Person
END

Comment: Hi s_nair! as far as I understand implementing query this way, would require putting it in the button_click method, since it will create table and insert item subsequently. I've tried to do that, but I failed to accomplish anything.I inserted my best version of it, in the code, I would appreciate If you look it up and correct it. Thank you!